# Dynamic page pagination is not working in react table

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I am using `react-table` v7 to generate a table. And now I am trying to make page size pagination dynamically by writing this

```
       <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              id="demo-simple-select"
              value={pageSize}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
              }}
            >
              {page.length > 10 ? (
                <MenuItem id={10} value={10} key={10}>
                  Show 10
                </MenuItem>
              ) : (
                [10, 20].map((pageSize) => (
                  <MenuItem value={pageSize} key={pageSize}>
                    Show {pageSize}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))
              )}
        </Select>
```

If page (rows) length is over 10, it shows two options `Show 10` and `Show 20`, but when I select `Show 20`, dropdown value doesn't show value anymore

[image]

And I get a warning in console `Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value '20' for the select component. Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''. The available values are '10'.`

It works fine if I remove ternary operator in `{page.length > 10 ? ..` and just put `[10,20,30].map() ..`

Answer (score 0):

If for the initial rendering, the value of `page.length` is over 10, the drop-down list will only display `Show 10` because that's what your logic states. If that's really what you want and your problem is the non-displayed values, it works by changing `MenuItem` to `option`, with both `select` and `option` non-capitalized (in react-table 7.7.0):

```
<select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
      id="demo-simple-select"
      value={pageSize}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
      }}
    >
      {page.length > 10 ? (
        <option id={10} value={10} key={10}>
          Show 10
        </option>
      ) : (
        [10, 20].map((pageSize) => (
          <option value={pageSize} key={pageSize}>
            Show {pageSize}
          </option>
        ))
      )}
</select>
```

On the other hand, if what you want is to give the option of displaying only the `Show 10` option when you have less than 10 rows, then change the `>` to `<` in the ternary operator check. That way you'll give (dynamically) the option of displaying only `Show 10` if there are less than 10 rows, or both options, `Show 10` and `Show 20`, when there are 10 rows or more.